# Nabla operator problem in vector calculus - laplacian is a scalar multiple of $f$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, solution-verification, vector-analysis

Let $f(\underline{r})=\frac{e^{-\lambda r}}{r}$, where $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ and $r=|\underline{r}|$. Find $\nabla f$.

My idea was to write $f(\underline r)=\frac{1}{(r_1^2\underline e_1+\cdots +r_n^2\underline e_n)}^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{-\lambda(r_1^2e_1+\cdots +r_n^2e_n)}$, supposing we are in $n$ dimensional space. Now we can find the $a$th derivative. But I just get caught up in a total algebraic mess and I can't help but think there must be an easier method.

Comment: First make sure you have the length of the vector correct :).

Comment: @ajr corrected, thanks! Any ideas how to proceed?

Comment: Not yet, the length of the vector should not contain any vectors (i.e. $e_n$'s), also there's a $1/2$ missing in the exponent. The computation isn't that bad once you note that it suffices to look at one coordinate.

Comment: It should be helpful if you start by computing any partial derivative of $(r_1^2+\ldots+r_n^2)^{1/2}$

Answer (score 1):

The function writes
$$
f(r) = \frac{e^{-\lambda r}}{r}
$$
it follows
$$
df = 
f'(r) dr =
\frac{-(\lambda r+1) e^{-\lambda r}}{r^2} dr
$$
Here
$r^2 = \| \mathbf{x} \|^2$
from which we deduce
$2 r dr = 2 \mathbf{x}^T d\mathbf{x}$
and thus
$dr = \frac{1}{r} \mathbf{x}^T d\mathbf{x}$.

The gradient writes
$$
\nabla f 
=
\frac{f'(r)}{r} \mathbf{x}
= 
\frac{-(\lambda r+1) e^{-\lambda r}}{r^3} \mathbf{x}
$$